# Using Data from different 2 data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I have 2 different DE lists like this:

First DE have information with FruitsType and FruitsExpirationDate

Second DE have information for the links

I'm wondering if we can use different DE to get those informations?
Basically I need to show the links depending on the FruitsType and FruitsExpirationDate from different DE

My condition for the fruits:

```
%%[
SET @TestLink = lookup('Fruits_Catalogue', 'FruitsExpirationDate' ,'FruitsType', 'LinkHero')
]%%

<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@TestLink )=%%" target="_blank">Click Link</a>
```

When I use that script, the link goes blank, is it possible to do this?

Comment: That’s not how you use arguments with Lookup function. Please check documentation and use the appropriate parameter and ampscript variable to identify the correct record in the Fruits_Catalogue data extension.